# Building image with Dockerfile is not using existing layers?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, podman

I'm quite new to Dockerfiles and not sure whats going on here. I'm using Podman and building a new image with a Dockerfile to set some additional permissions using a base image from Docker Hub. According to the layers (#8) in this [base image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/itext/dito-sdk/2.4.5/images/sha256-d7fbf8d8272562d2fe47d76fb12ead4bd277b5f5b48261e8192a5bc0143ba335?context=explore) it seems that the variabele SDKMAN_DIR is being set to `/home/javaUser/.sdkman`.

```
/bin/sh -c export SDKMAN_DIR="/home/javaUser/.sdkman" && curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

However, when I build a new image based on the newly created image with the Dockerfile, start a new container, exec into container and execute the command `echo $SDKMAN_DIR`, the result is empty. I was expecting that my variant of the image had the same variabels set.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

```
bash-5.1$ echo $SDKMAN_DIR
```

Below you'll find the Dockerfile I'm using.

```
FROM docker.io/itext/dito-sdk:2.4.5

# Make available to rootless users
USER root

RUN chmod g+x /home/javaUser/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh

# Become rootless user
USER 2000

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash -c "source /home/javaUser/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh && kotlin /opt/dito/startup-prepare.main.kts && java -jar /opt/dito/dito-sdk-docker.jar server /etc/opt/dito/config.yml"
```

Thanks in advance.

### Edit

Somehow I got it to work by passing in an `ENV`. Still I'm not exactly sure why the variable is not available without explicitly defining an `ENV` variable. Does this has to do with not being the `root` but `2000` user after an `exec` into the container?

### Edit

The variable is not available at runtime because of the fact that the variabele is being declared in the `RUN` step, and therefore only limited to that scope. Thanks to @DavidMaze for clarifying.

Comment: In that Docker Hub listing I don't see an `ENV` setting for that directory, only a couple of `export SDKMAN_DIR=...` commands inside `RUN` statements that get reset at the end of their respective `RUN` lines.  This is a typical reason to avoid version managers inside Dockerfiles; starting from a base image like `eclipse-temurin:17` that already includes the specific language tools or runtime you need is usually a better practice.  (A `/home` directory inside an image is also somewhat unusual.)  Is there a more straightforward base image that provides the tools you need?

Comment: Thanks for the response @DavidMaze, while I was editing the original post your comment was being added. `ENV` indeed seems to be the solution here. Thank you for clarifying the scope of the `RUN` statement. I didn't know that, now I do.
I needed the iText DITO SDK. This base image is provided by them. Therefore I'm not sure if I can created a completely new image without depending on their base image. Somehow I would need to get the `dito-sdk-docker.jar` but I'm not sure where to get this. It's probably being added in the 16th layer of the base image.